# how to say yes to the question "do you want me to take a look?" in a polite way

Tags: word-usage, usage

how to say yes in a polite way to the following question.  for example to our

supervisor.i want to know a polite way to answer the above question.

"do you want me to take a look?"

Answer (score 1):

"Yes.  I'd really like your input."

"If you don't mind."

"Yes.  That would be nice."

"I'd appreciate that!"

Answer (score 0):

**If you please**

1. a polite phrase indicating assent to a suggestion.

Example:

Bill: Shall I unload the car?

Jane: If you please.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+you+please